# Retrieving field values for previous Podio item revisions

Tags: python, podio

I'm working on something that requires me to retrieve the previous values of fields from previous revisions. I'm trying to product a list of dictionaries in Python where each dictionary will have values for every field from an item at the time of that revision.

I noticed that that [the revisions endpoint](https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/get-item-revisions-22372) doesn't give me the field values for prior revisions. The only way I could see that I could retrieve the values of prior revisions is if I use the get [item revision difference endpoint](https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/get-item-revision-difference-22374) and check for any update to any fields. Any fields that aren't updated from one revision to another will then have to inherit the values of the prior revision. Is the only way to get prior revision values to use the [item revision difference endpoint](https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/get-item-revision-difference-22374) or is there a different way?

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example